# Django - alter post data in CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to change a value in a post request but am getting the following error:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "owner" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (30, 123, G, null) <--> (index, number, type, owner)
```

The form itself:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.number}}
    {{form.type}}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{variable}}" name="owner">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

The request.POST data:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['TN3yNiGcvAso6V1UYZDHpyIQ1sNTMqDICPSqX2sftVpZfX6drambOkzoGBECLKcN'], 'number': ['123'], 'type': ['G'], 'owner': ['']}>
```

To modify the data:

```
class NodeCreateView(CreateView):

model = Node
form_class = NodeCreateForm
...

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    request.POST = request.POST.copy()
    request.POST['owner'] = 2
    return super(NodeCreateView, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```

The updated POST data:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['TN3yNiGcvAso6V1UYZDHpyIQ1sNTMqDICPSqX2sftVpZfX6drambOkzoGBECLKcN'], 'number': ['123'], 'type': ['G'], 'owner': [2]}>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to include the owner as a hidden input, or modify the post data like this.

First, exclude the owner from your form:

```
class NodeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Node
        exclude = ['owner']
```

Then in your view, override the `form_valid` method, and set the `owner_id` on the instance:

```
class NodeCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Node
    form_class = NodeCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner_id = 2
        return super(NodeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I'm assuming owner is a foreign key, otherwise set `form.instance.owner = 2`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Will modifying the form_valid() method also work when the model's clean() method needs access to the field that you want to set in the form_valid() method? Or does form_valid() get called after the model's clean() method?

Comment: @DevinGilbert `form_valid` is only called if the form is valid, so a model form will call the model’s `clean` method before `form_valid` is called

Answer (score 2):

You're correctly mutating `request.POST` by using `copy()`, but passing the modified request object into `super().post()` is misleading. If you follow the call chain back to where the view is actually accessing the request object, it's not using your modified request, it's using the un-modified request as `self.request`. See [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L44).

There is probably a better way to accomplish whatever it is you're doing, but if it's nothing permanent, you can just override `get_form_kwargs()` in your `NodeCreateView`.

Answer (score 1):

for your case better way to override `get_form_kwargs`, for example:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(NodeCreateView).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['data'].update({'owner': 2})
    return kwargs
```